# Qt "Copy/Paste/Cut"

Tags: qt, copy, paste, cut

Well, i'm doing a Text Editor, basically where you write the text is a "QPlainTextEdit" i'm having issues, i'm trying to do in "Edit" Menu, an option to Copy/Paste/Cut.

With Copy i meant, you select the text in the Editor, open Edit Menu, Click Copy and sends that to Clipboard.
Paste, pastes what you copied?
Cut, cuts the selected text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QTextEdit` has slots `copy`, `paste` and `cut`. So, You need just connect Your signals with these slots and You will have C-c\C-v functionality. You can do that in QDesigner without coding.